# QR code,Augmented reality android app for supermarket users

Tags: android, qr-code, augmented-reality

I need to develop an android app for supermarkets. when user's mobile phone camera detect a QR code of a particular item, if that item has a promotion it will pop up a message which has promotion details. this needs to be done using augmented reality(QR code image recognition). Also that pop up message should have a button which user can view the information of that item(e.g price,Exp.date) when clicks on that button.the item info is embedded in the QR code.item info can be retrieved using QR  code scanner.

I am planning to use openCV for AR for the first part and for the second part a QRcode scanner. Is this possible to do both of the functions in one go(AR using QR code image recognition and QR code scanner) if so could you recommend me what sdk tools to be used in Android studio ?
If there are any easy ways could you suggest me?

Comment: Just to clarify - you can do an app that does AR by QR code recognition (any image works, you just need certain pivot points), and also a QR code scanner, but the bigger question here is, do you really want to do that? Have you though about user experience and usability if you merge two crucial functions of the app into one? I would suggest you make some wire-frames first, consult a UX expert, investigate the libraries in question and identify any potential risks and spikes that needed to be done before moving forward.

Comment: From you description it seems to me that you actually don't need anything AR related. A simple qr recognition code should be enough to open a popup with some details. Am I right?

Comment: Then can I add a button to the GUI which displays the results of of the QR code scanner? if user wants to buy taht item, the user can click on that button it will add the price of that item to the user's bill which also included in the user's app

Comment: What are you describing here is a pure Android application which does not need any "AR features", not even OpenCV I would say. On the client side (the Android app) you would only need to fetch the camera frames and send them to a server which recognizes the image and sends back the result which is displayed on the smartphone. Of course it depends on the number of images that you plan to recognize but I would do it like that. In any case, there's no AR involved in what you described here.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/). It is a AR SDK for Android, iOS and Unity.
Vuforia let's you import a set of Images or simple 3D objects which need to be recognized and works offline for small amount of "markers" and online for large amount of markers.